# Powerapps Gallery with different DataSources (List)

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

Team,

I have 4 SharePoint Lists representing country information. Country1, Country 2 and Country3. I am patching data to the lists via an If Statement based on the Country selected in a dropdown.

Now, the challenge now is to edit/update the differenet lists using a dynamic datasource control since the datasource is not in one list.

I am looking at a solution where I can edit/update records based on the country selected.

Any workaround?